# Please identify this syrphid (hoverfly)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Last summer I took these pictures of a member of the Syrphidae on my balcony (Switzerland, Geneva area, Alt. ~380m, June 2020 @19:14)

Pictures:

[image: Scaeva sp.-1]
[image: Scaeva sp.-2]
[image: Scaeva sp.-3]
[image: Scaeva sp.-4]
[image: Scaeva sp.-5]
[image: Scaeva sp.-6]
[image: Scaeva sp.-7]
[image: Scaeva sp.-8]

I hesitate between three species but it could also be another one:

- *Scaeva dignota*
- *Scaeva selenitica*
- *Scaeva pyrastri*

Because the pale marks on tergites 3 and 4 seems parallel to the anterior margins of the tergites, I would eliminate the third one, especially because the marks are also more yellowish than white.
For the two other species, I am not sure because I checked many pictures on the internet, but some are wrongly tagged (google images results).

Any entomologist can confirm the exact species of this hoverfly?

Comment: Awsome pictures, we have them in Austria too ;) Personally I tend to the _'Scaeva selenitica'_, but that's just my uneducated guess..